# two spinners that rely on one spinner for array/entries

Tags: android, arrays

Hi I am making a converter app (just like the one when you google "temperature converter") So I have one spinner making two other spinners show the same array. I know theres code out there for this but i have not found some that deals with many different arrays. For instance I need one Spinner to be able to make the two other spinners show the same array but i have many different arrays to pic from (temperature/length/mass/speed/volume/area/time)

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="units">
    <item>Temperature</item>
    <item>Length</item>
    <item>Mass</item>
    <item>Speed</item>
    <item>Volume</item>
    <item>Area</item>
    <item>Time</item>    
   </string-array>

   <string-array name="Temperature">
    <item>Celsius</item>
    <item>Fahrenheit</item>     
   </string-array>


      <string-array name="Mass">
    <item>Metric Ton</item>
    <item>Kilogram</item>
    <item>Gram</item>
    <item>Milligram</item>
    <item>Pound</item>
    <item>Ounce</item>
   </string-array>

   <string-array name="Length">
    <item>Kilometer</item>
    <item>Meter</item>
    <item>Centimeter</item>
    <item>Millimeter</item>
    <item>Mile</item>
    <item>Yard</item>
    <item>Foot</item>
    <item>Inch</item>           
   </string-array>

   <string-array name="Speed">
    <item>Miles/Hour</item>
    <item>Feet/Sec</item>
    <item>Meters/Sec</item>
    <item>Km/Hour</item>
    <item>Knot</item>
   </string-array>

   <string-array name="Time">
    <item>Nanosecond</item>
    <item>Microsecond</item>
    <item>Meters/Sec</item>
    <item>Km/Hour</item>
    <item>Knot</item>
   </string-array>

   <string-array name="Area">
    <item>Square km</item>
    <item>Square meter</item>
    <item>Square mile</item>
    <item>Hectare</item>
    <item>Acre</item>
    <item>Square yard</item>
    <item>Square foot</item>
    <item>Square inch</item>

   </string-array>

   <string-array name="Area2">
    <item>Square km</item>
    <item>Square meter</item>
    <item>Square mile</item>
    <item>Hectare</item>
    <item>Acre</item>
    <item>Square yard</item>
    <item>Square foot</item>
    <item>Square inch</item>

    </string-array>
```

Layout Xml File

```
  <Spinner
  android:id="@+id/selector1"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />

  <Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinner_unit"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
  android:entries="@array/units" />

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/equelsbutton"
  android:layout_width="80dp"
  android:layout_height="80dp"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
  android:background="@color/clear"
  android:text="@string/equels"
  android:textSize="40sp" />

 <Spinner
  android:id="@+id/selector2"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/selector1" />

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/selector2"
  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Converter_Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class Converter_Activity extends Activity {

public Spinner spinnerunits;
 public Spinner spinnerpicker1;
 public Spinner spinnerpicker2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.conveter_activity);

spinnerunits = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_unit);

spinnerpicker1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selector1);

spinnerpicker2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selector2);



}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi i modified the Converter_Activity.java class. Please try with the latest source code.  Its working fine for me. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks.

**Converter_Activity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Converter_Activity extends Activity {
     public static Spinner spinnerunits;
     public static Spinner spinnerpicker1;
     public static Spinner spinnerpicker2;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.spinnerlayout);
       spinnerunits = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_unit);
       spinnerpicker1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selector1);
       spinnerpicker2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selector2);

       ArrayAdapter <String> arrayUnits = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.units));
       arrayUnits.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinnerunits .setAdapter(arrayUnits);

       spinnerunits.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
               if(spinnerunits.getSelectedItem().equals("Temperature"))
           {
               ArrayAdapter <String> s1 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Temperature));
               s1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               spinnerpicker2.setAdapter(s1);
               spinnerpicker1.setAdapter(s1);
           }else  if(spinnerunits.getSelectedItem().equals("Mass"))
           {
               ArrayAdapter <String> s2 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Mass));
               s2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               spinnerpicker2.setAdapter(s2);
               spinnerpicker1.setAdapter(s2);
           }
           else  if(spinnerunits.getSelectedItem().equals("Speed"))
           {
               ArrayAdapter <String> s3 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Speed));
               s3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               spinnerpicker2.setAdapter(s3);
               spinnerpicker1.setAdapter(s3);
           }
           else  if(spinnerunits.getSelectedItem().equals("Area"))
           {
               ArrayAdapter <String> s4 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Area));
               s4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               spinnerpicker2.setAdapter(s4);
               spinnerpicker1.setAdapter(s4);
           }
           else  if(spinnerunits.getSelectedItem().equals("Time"))
           {
               ArrayAdapter <String> s5 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Time));
               s5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               spinnerpicker2.setAdapter(s5);
               spinnerpicker1.setAdapter(s5);
           }
           }

           @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
            }  
       });
   }     
}
```

Please try this code and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I add the "ListItem Selection Event Handler" I get rid of all the errors but when I launch the app and select the converter section it comes up with an error and crashes. "I have declared the activity in the manifest" and I'm not sure why this is happening because there are no errors. So if you know and could tell me that would be grate. Thanks

Comment: Hi added the Converter_Activity.java for you. Please try this code and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again I'm not get in any error messages with this but when i select the spinner it dose not affect the spinners. Also in the code you put spinner1 as the selector spinner? I'm wondering if you did that on per pose because  i would like Spinnerunits to select the units to be shown on the other two spinners (1/2)

Comment: Oh and when i change all the spinner1's to spinnerunit the array dose not get displayed in spinnerunit spinner when i test the app. Thanks.